# Wordpress contact form 7 image instead of radio button

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image, radio-button

As the title suggest, I would like to use images instead of radio buttons so the user could select the picture. I know that there is a solution on here with modifying the php code but that seems to be outdated. I also saw this https://jsfiddle.net/La8wQ/10/ solution which would work great if the plugin would generate the html the same way as in the example.

Instead it looks like this on my page:

```
<span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">::before Type 1 ::after</span>
<input type="radio" name="type-of-website" value="Type 1" checked="checked">
</span>
```

This is for each type I have added. I know I can warp it in a label but I don't see how it would help in this situation. I would like to stick to showed example because that uses pure css.

I guess my question is in the end, how could I make it work in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

For this to work you need to do a few things. Make radiobuttons, with `<label></label>` directly below/after them. This is not a default WPCF7 label. The radiobuttons need to have an `id=""` that is same as the `for=""` part of the label above it.

A `<label>` needs a class added (for example `visa`) which has its image defined in the CSS like so: `.visa{background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png);}`.

A `<label>` needs this class as well: `drinkcard-cc`.

Each radiobutton needs class `wpcf7-special-radio` added to it.

For 2 radiobuttons an example looks like this:

HTML

```
<form>
    <div>
      <span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
      <input id="special_radio_1" type="radio" class="wpcf7-special-radio" name="type-of-website" value="Type 1"/>
      <label for="special_radio_1" class="drinkcard-cc visa"></label>
      <input id="special_radio_2" type="radio" class="wpcf7-special-radio" name="type-of-website" value="Type 2"/>
      <label for="special_radio_2" class="drinkcard-cc mastercard"></label>
      </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.wpcf7-special-radio {
    margin:0;padding:0;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
       -moz-appearance:none;
            appearance:none;
}
.visa{background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png);}
.mastercard{background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png);}

.wpcf7-special-radio:active +.drinkcard-cc{opacity: .9;}
.wpcf7-special-radio:checked +.drinkcard-cc{
    -webkit-filter: none;
       -moz-filter: none;
            filter: none;
}
.drinkcard-cc{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;height:70px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
            filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}
.drinkcard-cc:hover{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
            filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}
```

And here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Snuwerd/9r1dz0uk/

**Update**

Correction, the label needs to be after/below the input, like in the example code.

**Update**

It is not possible without JS, because you can't assign seperate IDs to radio elements in WPCF7, so here is the JS solution:

Use this CSS:

```
.wpcf7-special-radio-container .wpcf7-list-item-label {
 display: none;
}
.wpcf7-special-radio {
    margin:0;padding:0;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
       -moz-appearance:none;
            appearance:none;
}
.special_radio_card_0 { background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png); }
.special_radio_card_1 { background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png); }
.special_radio_card_2 { background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png); }
.special_radio_card_3 { background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png); }
.special_radio_card_4 { background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png); }
.special_radio_card_5 { background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png); }

.wpcf7-special-radio:active +.drinkcard-cc{opacity: .9;}
.wpcf7-special-radio:checked +.drinkcard-cc{
    -webkit-filter: none;
       -moz-filter: none;
            filter: none;
}
.drinkcard-cc{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;height:70px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
            filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}
.drinkcard-cc:hover{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
            filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}
```

Be sure not to add any white (empty) lines inside the `<script></script>` tag, or else it will break, because WPCF7 will place paragraphs (`<p>`) in the code. Paste this in your form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"> <label> Your Name * [text* your-name] </label> </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> <label> Your Email * [email* your-email] </label> </div>
</div>
<label> Subject [text your-subject] </label> <label> Your Message [textarea your-message] </label>

[radio type-of-website class:wpcf7-special-radio-container default:1 "Type 1" "Type 2"]
[submit "Send"]

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    $('.wpcf7-special-radio-container input').addClass('wpcf7-special-radio');
    $('.wpcf7-special-radio').each(function (index, el) {
        var label = $('<label>').attr('for', 'special_radio_'+index).addClass('drinkcard-cc').addClass('special_radio_card_'+index);
        $(this).attr('id', 'special_radio_'+index);
        $(this).after(label);
    }); 
});
</script>
```

You can add new options in the radio like so

2 options:
`[radio type-of-website class:wpcf7-special-radio-container default:1 "Type 1" "Type 2"]`

4 options: `[radio type-of-website class:wpcf7-special-radio-container default:1 "Type 1" "Type 2" "Type 3" "Type 4"]`

And they will be mapped in order with the images that are chosen in the CSS code on these lines:

```
.special_radio_card_0 { background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png); }
.special_radio_card_1 { background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png); }
.special_radio_card_2 { background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png); }
.special_radio_card_3 { background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png); }
.special_radio_card_4 { background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png); }
.special_radio_card_5 { background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png); }
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The only thing I can not figure out now, is how to insert the label tag using the plugin. Because googling this issue results in other confused people. I tired adding it manually in the plugin but that breaks everything. I also can not add id to every single option, only to the full form.

Comment: Just add the html directly into the form. You can use HTML inside a CF7 form. Can you post the form code? And maybe also the HTML code that the form generates on the page.

Comment: `<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <label> Your Name *
  [text* your-name] </label>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <label> Your Email *
    [email* your-email] </label>
 </div>
</div>

<label> Subject
    [text your-subject] </label>

<label> Your Message
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[radio type-of-website class:cc-selector default:1 "Type 1" "Type 2"]



[submit "Send"]` This is how the CP7 looks like, I can't post the generated html because it would be too long for a comment. But its basically how my original code looks like.

Comment: I did some extra research and have to disappoint you. Because you can't assign seperate IDs to the radio options with CF7, what you want is not possible without JS. I could make a script that makes it possible, you would just paste it at the bottom of the CF7 form.

Comment: Yea, I was about to say the same. It's quiet sad actually. I would really appreciate it if you help me with the js.

Comment: No problem @Criticalbarny